# How to improve terrible MongoDB query performance when aggregating with arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data schema consisting of many updates (hundreds of thousands+ per entity) that are assigned to entities.  I'm representing this with a single top-level document for each of the entities and an array of updates under each of them.  The schema for those top-level documents looks like this:

```
{
  "entity_id": "uuid",
  "updates": [
    { "timestamp": Date(...), "value": 10 },
    { "timestamp": Date(...), "value": 11 }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a query that returns the number of entities that have received an update within the past n hours.  All updates in the `updates` array are guaranteed to be sorted by virtue of the manner in which they're updated by my application.  I've created the following aggregation to do this:

```js
db.getCollection('updates').aggregate([
  {"$project": {last_update: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$updates", -1]}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {newRoot: "$last_update"}},
  {"$match": {timestamp: {"$gte": new Date(...)}}},
  {"$count": "count"}
])
```

For some reason that I don't understand, the query I just pasted takes an absurd amount of time to complete.  It exhausts the 15-second timeout on the client I use, as a matter of fact.

From a time complexity point of view, this query looks incredibly cheap (which is part of the way I designed this schema that way I did).  It looks to be linear with respect to the total number of top-level documents in the collection which are then filtered down, of which there are less than 10,000.

The confusing part is that it doesn't seem to be the `$project` step which is expensive.  If I run that one alone, the query completes in under 2 seconds.  However, just adding the `$match` step makes it time out and shows large amounts of CPU and IO usage on the server the database is running on.  My best guess is that it's doing some operations on the full update array for some reason, which makes no sense since the first step explicitly limits it to only the last element.

Is there any way I can improve the performance of this aggregation?  Does having all of the updates in a single array like this somehow cause Mongo to not be able to create optimal queries even if the array access patterns are efficient themselves?

Would it be better to do what I was doing previously and store each update as a top-level document tagged with the id of its parent entity?  This is what I was doing previously, but performance was quite bad and I figured I'd try this schema instead in an effort to improve it.  So far, the experience has been the opposite of what I was expecting/hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing, it will enhance the performance of your query.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

For that use the mongo compass to check which index is used most then one by one index them to improve the performance of it.

After that fetch on the fields which you require in the end, with projection in aggregation.

I hope this might solve your issue. But i would suggest that go for indexing first. Its a huge PLUS in case of large data fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You need to support your query with an index and simplify it as much as possible.

You're querying against the `timestamp` field of the first element of the `updates` field, so add an index for that:

```
db.updates.createIndex({'updates.0.timestamp': 1})
```

You're just looking for a count, so get that directly:

```
db.updates.count({'updates.0.timestamp': {$gte: new Date(...)}})
```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for taking the time to create an answer.  I don't think that this quite applies for what I'm trying to do.  My use case has updates inserted into the array in order from oldest to newest, so `.0` would look at the oldest update rather than the newest.  I could modify my application code that populates the updates to inset into the front of the array rather than the back, but that seems counter-intuitive.  Also, I created the index as specified here, but it didn't seem to help performance for my original query at all (which doesn't surprise me given its semantics)

Comment: I just realized that I put `0` into my example instead of `-1`...  I'm very sorry.  I've corrected the example.

Comment: If you don't want to change the order of the elements in `updates`, keep a separate field to contain the timestamp of the latest update and set that as you update. Then you can index and query against that new field.